# Alphabetically Sort Grid Items

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I have this Stackpanel with a Grid, and in the grid a multiple amount of buttons which contain content to display. The items are alphabetically ordered, and I have do this manually. For example if the name of a game would be "Death Row", I would have to waste time manually moving every item down one so I could make room for the new item. The question here would be, is there a way to organize it so that I could just implement code inbetween to items and it would automatically adjust?
How the code looks:
[Code](http://speedcap.net/sharing/files/d6/08/d6085ccea914b816d14afa53ba025b11.png)
[Example Image](http://speedcap.net/sharing/files/3a/53/3a53d132a94b4974b32171e0a7edfd9c.png)

Comment: Why Do you post your code as .png?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a `DataGrid` to Layout dynamic content, rather use an `ItemsControl` with `DataTemplates` and store you data in a collection in a `ViewModel` and then use databinding to display your content.  This will allow you to change your data collection and have your UI update appropriately.

Example:

A simple class to hold the details of each game:

```
public class GameViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

Your main ViewModel:

```
public class SortedContentViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<GameViewModel> GameList { get; set; }

    public SortedContentViewModel()
    {
        GameList = new ObservableCollection<GameViewModel>()
        {
            new GameViewModel() {Name="Brink", ImagePath = @"Resources/brink.png" },
            new GameViewModel() {Name="Bulletstorm", ImagePath = @"Resources/bulletstorm.png" }
        };
    }
}
```

and your XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Wpf_Playground.Views.SortedContentView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Wpf_Playground.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{DynamicResource ViewModel}">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:SortedContentViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:GameViewModel}">
        <Button>
            <Grid>
                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Stretch="Fill" />
                <Border Background="#66000000" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="10,-2,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameList}" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thanks, and I get how you're doing it, but nothing seems to appear. Here is the new code: [XAML]http://speedcap.net/sharing/files/a0/5d/a05def47065215562e54aad70e59e56f.png [C#]http://speedcap.net/sharing/files/f0/a0/f0a014aa004bc9b38bb8c7de5c219a9e.png . On top of the XAML, I have put DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}", so that it would reference itself.

Comment: Your `DataContext` binding is not working how you think. Look at your outout window and I bet you see a binding error.  If you want to do it all in the code behind, then get rid of your `"DataContext=..."` in your XAML and just put `this.DataContext = this;` in your window constructor.

Comment: Thanks. I figured it did since it was working with another ListView I had on the form.